# deploying a simple ERC721 contract: transaction could not be decoded: could not recover secp256k1 key: calculated Rx is larger than curve P

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts, nft

**You can check out the code here:** https://github.com/lopeselio/Chainlink-VH-DynamicNFT

Command:

```
truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby -f 3
```

Then response is as follows:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'rinkeby'
> Network id:      4
> Block gas limit: 10000000 (0x989680)


3_NFT_simple.js
===============

   Deploying 'NFTSimple'
   ---------------------

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"NFTSimple" -- transaction could not be decoded: could not recover secp256k1 key: calculated Rx is larger than curve P.

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:365:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at Migration._deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:74:1)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:61:1)
    at Migration.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:212:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:258:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:228:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:136:1)
Truffle v5.2.5 (core: 5.2.5)
Node v15.5.0
```

My truffle-config.js:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
require('dotenv').config();
// require('babel-polyfill');
// require('babel-register');

const mnemonic = process.env.MNEMONIC
const url = process.env.RPC_URL

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    cldev: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*',
    },
    ganache: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 7545,
      network_id: '*',
    },
    kovan: {
      provider: () => {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, url)
      },
      network_id: '42',
      skipDryRun: true
    },
    rinkeby: {
      provider: () => {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, url)
      },
      network_id: '4',
      skipDryRun: true,
      networkCheckTimeout: 999999
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.12",
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 1
      }
    }
  },
  api_keys: {
    etherscan: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  },
  plugins: [
    'truffle-plugin-verify'
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: What version of HDWallet are you using? Newer versions changed the instantiation parameters, check if that is the casehttps://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/hdwallet-provider. The error message is saying the signature is wrong, you might try generating a new mnemonic.

Comment: Hey @Ismael thanks for reaching out. I have verified and used the latest version mentioned in the repo v1.2.4

Comment: @Ismael, I have updated by truffle-config.js according to the latest instantiations in v1.2.4. could you help me check it out.... [1](https://github.com/lopeselio/Chainlink-VH-DynamicNFT)

Comment: [Link to the repo](https://github.com/lopeselio/Chainlink-VH-DynamicNFT) I am using v1.2.4 I have also changed the instantiations to the one listed in the repo.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with hdwallet-provider https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3940. Downgrading to 1.2.2 seems to work with ganache-cli.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has this problem and the install of HDWallet version 1.2.3 is not working, check the HDWallet version used for the project on **package.json** file. If the version is different from the installed, you need to install it using the command `--save`:

```
npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider@1.2.3 --save
```

And be sure that you are doing this command on the **root** folder of the project:

```
C://.../your_project > npm install...
```